# How do I get Attributes from Core Data into an Array for - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, core-data

I'm trying to retrieve data from Core Data and put it into a Mutable Array

I have an Entity called 'Stock' and in Properties, attributes called : code, price & description...

How do I get the data stored in these attributes into a simple Mutable Array?

---

I've added this code...

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:[stock valueForKey:@"code"]];
```

and I get this error...

```
'-[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

I have a 'Managed Object Class' called 'Stock' and declared called stock.  Am I missing something?

---

If I do this in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`...

```
Stock   *stock1  = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:stock1.code];

NSLog(@"Filtered List is? %@", array);
```

In the console I can see these 2 items

```
'The Filtered array is 810005'
'The Filtered array is 810007
```

'

What must I do to get these items(810005 & 810007) into an array set up in the `-viewDidLoad` method? Like it does in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

### Update

Hi Marcus,

Finally got it working (well, 80%)

I put this in the `-cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
Stock *product = nil;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{   

    filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:stock1.code, nil];

    product = [self.filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self configureFilteredCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    [filteredListContent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Filtered List Array List is? %@", stock1.code);
}
else 
{
    listContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:stock1.code, nil];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSLog(@"List Array List is?          %@", stock1.code);
}
```

Then I used this code in the scope

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    self.savedSearchTerm = searchText;

    if (searchText !=nil)
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code beginsWith[cd] %@", searchText];
        [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    }
    else
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate =[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code contains[cd] %@", searchText];
        [fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error])
    {
        // Handle error
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        exit(-1);  // Fail
    }           

    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Everything is filtering fine but when I hit cancel on the search, it's not reloading the original data...

I won't be defeated...!!

Thanx

Comment: Why are you adding things to an array inside of the `-tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?  That method should be purely for display and  does not modify content.  By the time you reach that point you should only be accessing data that is in your `NSFetchedResultsController` or somewhere else and displaying it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are having this issue in your `-viewDidLoad`, I am guessing (and without the code from `-viewDidLoad`, it is only a guess) that you are trying to fetch objects from the `NSFetchedResultsController` before the `-executeFetch:` has been called on the controller and therefore you are in the land of nils.

I would suggest setting a break point in your `-viewDidLoad` and watching the values and you walk through your code.  This will tell you what is `nil` and where.

Of course a better question is, why are you trying to put `NSManagedObject` instances into a `NSMutableArray`?  Since they are already in your `NSFetchedResultsController` is there really a need to build up another array?  What is the end goal?

## Update

Now I understand what you are trying to do.

### Solution 1

Only populate the array when a search has been conducted.  Take a look at the http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/index.html example code and you should see how to apply it to your situation.

If you want to *enter* the table view with a pre-defined search then you need to perform it after you have executed a `-performFetch:` in the `NSFetchedResultsController`.

### Solution 2

Modify the `NSPredicate` on the `NSFetchedResultsController` to include your search terms and then execute `-performFetch:` on the `NSFetchedResultsController`, you may have to do a `-reloadData` on the table as well, I am not sure.

When the user clears the search field you reset the predicate and re-fetch everything.  Since it is all cached there should be no performance penalty.

Solution 2 just occurred to me and I have not tested it personally but there is no reason it shouldn't work just fine.  Should even give you live updates within the search.

Comment: Hi Marcus,

Really I'm trying to use an 'Search Display controller'.  I did it in Sqlite by pulling the data into an array.  I was trying to find a way to use it in core data and predicate.  I know there must be an easy way to do this in Core Data but I can't seem to find a way...

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'm reading through your book trying to understand core data inside out...

I'm surprised to see you here...

You've pointed me in the right direction...

Thanx for your help so far...

Comment: First time back at SO since last evening ... this makes a LOT more sense now. This is why it's a good idea to state your goal in your original question. It saves unnecessary guessing at what you're trying to do (and useless explanations about things you're not trying to do). :-)

Comment: (ran out of room) I'd say solution 2 is actually the #1 solution. If you drag entities from your model into IB, you can examine how it automatically sets up a search field purely with Cocoa Bindings (using the information from your model).

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation? You [fetch](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484) your Stock instances (all of them or filter them with a predicate), then do with them whatever you please.

You can then add their properties to an array individually:

```
[array addObject:[stockInstance valueForKey:@"price"];
```

... or use a combination of < NSKeyValueCoding > protocol methods such as `-dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:` NSDictionary methods such as `-objectsForKeys:notFoundMarker:` to get an array for given keys.

This may or may not actually be what you need to do, though. It depends on what you intend to use the resulting array for. If you want a quick sum of all matching Stock instances' "price" values, for example, you can use [Set and Array Operators](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html). It really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Joshua,

I've added this code...
 NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [array addObject:[stock valueForKey:@"code"]];

and I get an error...
'-[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'

I have a 'Managed Object Class' called 'Stock' and declared called stock

Am I missing something?

Comment: You cannot insert nil into an array. Only real objects (including) [NSNull null]. You should guard against attempting insertion if "code" (or whatever) is nil

Comment: Hi Josh, The only thing is "code" has two item stored... :-(

I'll show, hold on...

Comment: Hi Marcus, I have your book in front of me 'Core Data, Data on Mac OS X' On Chapter 4 'Accessing Attributes'  That's basically what I'm trying to do.  It looks so easy...

Answer (score 1):

When I got your error,

```
'-[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil'
```

I had given the fetchedRequest a sort descriptor that had a nil key. The error appeared when I used these lines:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:NO];   
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

The error disappeared when I set the key to @"name":

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```